# Cordova SQLlite plugin how to get values form select?

Tags: json, sqlite, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I just installed this SQLlite plugin for Cordova:

https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

I would like to get returned results as JSON array, so i tried this:

```
 db.transaction(function(tx) {
     tx.executeSql("select * from dialed_calls;", [], function(tx, res) {
         console.log("tx object " +JSON.stringify(tx));
         console.log("res object " +JSON.stringify(res));
     });
 });
```

Problem is that none from returned objects contains response values from columns.

For example res object returns this:

```
{"rows":{"length":12},"rowsAffected":0}
```

**Question is:**

How can i get result with retuned rows as a JSON array?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5):

I solved it by this way:

```
db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name:"callplanner"});
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM planned_calls', [], function(tx,results) {
        for (var i=0; i < results.rows.length; i++){
            row = results.rows.item(i);
            console.log("row is " + JSON.stringify(row));
        }
    });
});
```